# How to join a string to a URL in Python?

Tags: python, url

I am trying to join a string in a URL, but the problem is that since it's spaced the other part does not get recognized as part of the URL.

Here would be an example:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
website = "http://example.php?id=1 order by 1--"
request = urllib2.Request(website)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
html = response.read()
```

The "`order by 1--`" part is not recognized as part of the URL.

Answer (score 4):

You should better use [`urllib.urlencode`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) or [`urllib.quote`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote):

```
website = "http://example.com/?" + urllib.quote("?id=1 order by 1--")
```

or

```
website = "http://example.com/?" + urllib.urlencode({"id": "1 order by 1 --"})
```

and about the query you're trying to achieve:

[image]

I think you're forgetting a `;` to end the first query.

Answer (score 2):

Of course not. Spaces are invalid in a query string, and should be replaced by `+`.

```
http://example.com/?1+2+3
```